# how to schedule a prefect flow that runs on first Tuesday of each month at 18:00 IST in prefect 1.x?

Tags: scheduler, intervals, scheduling, prefect

I want to set a schedule in prefect 1.x so that it starts the flow only on 1st Tuesday of each Monday, using code, I'd also like to see a way of doing this if I have a set of custom dates I want to run it on.

I couldn't do it since cron does not allow me to set it. Can you suggest a way , please be sure to suggest a solution that works with prefect 1.x

Answer (score 0):

in Prefect v1, you could solve it by using a combination of schedules, clocks, filters and adjustments. in v2, you could do that using RRule schedule